# Why AWS VPC Interface endpoints (when resource can be confined within VPC)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I am experimenting with AWS DMS right now. I see that AWS DMS supports both VPC (DMS replication instance has to be confined to a VPC during creation) and interface VPC endpoints.

Question: If a resource can be confined to a VPC, and by default, only other resources within the VPC can access the confined resource, then why do we even need support for interface VPC endpoints?

Comment: What do you mean by "AWS DMS supports"? Support in what sense? Any link to AWS docs description the support?

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation you are reading.

Comment: AWS DMS support for interface VPC endpoints: "To confine your communications with AWS DMS within a single VPC, you can create a VPC interface endpoint that enables you to connect to AWS DMS through AWS PrivateLink. " - from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/infrastructure-security.html

Comment: How to configure a VPC for the AWS DMS replication instance - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_ReplicationInstance.Creating.html

Answer (score 0):

The "interface VPC endpoint" is **not** for resources that DMS can use. It is for the DMS service itself. It means that you can use **AWS CLI/SDK** to directly interact with DMS service from within a VPC, without the need for the internet.

Without the interface VPC endpoint, all API calls to the DMS service go through the internet, which may be a security issue.

Comment: When DMS replication instance can be confined to a VPC, cant I directly interact with the DMS service (probably from an EC2 instance within the same VPC) without the need for the Internet ? In that case, why do I need to create a VPC interface endpoint?

Comment: @user1872325 DMS service has **public endponts** listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/dms.html). You always interact with DMS service through the internet, unless you use VPC interface endpoints. That's why they exist - to not use internet.

Comment: @user1872325 How did it go? Is it still unclear what interface VPC endpoint is for DMS?